# Is there a way of saving changes done in Google Chromes dev-tools directly to a SharePoint library?

Tags: development

Is there a way of saving changes done in Google Chromes dev-tools directly to a SharePoint library?

This would be a big time saver when editing and debugging CSS- och JavaScript-files!

Any ideas how you could build something that makes this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can access all the content from the dev tools. (see http://addyosmani.com/blog/autosave-changes-chrome-dev-tools/)

By using SharePoint's REST API you can easily save everything in a SharePoint library.